# Share common dependencies between contexts

Tags: javascript, requirejs

#### Premise

Let's say I have two different AMD-based AngularJS apps, each of them with their own sets of controllers, directives, services, etc. Each of them are bundled in their own `dist/{app-name}.min.js` and loaded in `<script>` tags in the same HTML page (this is all in the context of a CMS that then contains these apps among other things)

Now the apps end up sharing some of the services, directives, and vendor libraries like `angular` itself, `moment`, `jQuery`, etc, so I've made another folder for all of these resources, which results in a bundle that will be added to the page before the js bundles of the apps:

```
<script src="/some-path/dist/shared-resources.min.js"></script>
<script src="/some-path/dist/first-app.min.js"></script>
<script src="/some-path/dist/second-app.min.js"></script>
```

This is the resulting folder structure:

```
.
├── shared-resources/
│    ├── dist/
│    ├── src/
│    │     └── common/
│    │          ├── directives/
│    │          ├── modules/
│    │          ├── services/
│    │          └── vendor/
│    └── build.js
│
├── first-app
│    ├── dist/
│    ├── src/
│    │    ├── first-app/
│    │    │    ├── controllers/
│    │    │    ├── modules/
│    │    │    ├── services/
│    │    │    ├── directives/
│    │    │    └── app.js
│    │    └── first-app.js
│    └── build.js
│
└── second-app
     ├── dist/
     ├── src/
     │    ├── second-app/
     │    │    ├── controllers/
     │    │    ├── modules/
     │    │    ├── services/
     │    │    ├── vendor/
     │    │    └── app.js
     │    └── second-app.js
     └── build.js
```

This is an example of what the `build.js` file for the common modules looks like

```
({
    baseUrl: 'src',
    removeCombined: true,
    out: 'dist/shared-resources.min.js',
    paths: { // forcing a `common/{modulename}` convention
        'common/jquery': 'common/vendor/jquery.min',
        'common/moment': 'common/vendor/moment.min',
        'common/angular': 'common/vendor/angular/angular.min',
    },
    shim: {
        'common/angular': {
            exports: 'angular',
        }
    },
    include: [
        'common/modules/vendors', // Just a bundle of every vendor modules
        'common/directives/common-directive',
        'common/services/common-service'
    ],
})
```

Now my intention was to have all the shared modules being namespaced with `common/`, so each of the apps could require `common/angular`, `common/directives/common-directive`, and so on, and then exclude the `common` path when creating their bundle (since all the common modules are already present in the `shared-resources.js` bundle), for example:

```
// first-app/src/first-app/controllers/app-controller.js
define([
    'first-app/modules/controllers',
    'first-app/services/app-service',
    'common/services/common-service'
], function (controllers) {
    'use strict';

    controllers.controller('AppController', ['CommonService', 'AppService', function (CommonService, AppService) {
        CommonService.call();
        AppService.call();
    }]);
});

// first-app/build.js
({
    baseUrl: 'src',
    out: 'dist/first-app.min.js',
    paths: {
        'common': 'empty:'
    },
    name: 'first-app',
    deps: ['first-app/app']
})
```

#### Problem

The problem is how these two apps, which again are *both* loaded on the page (this can't be avoided), are supposed to correctly look up these common modules.

Given that each of the apps have obviously a different `baseUrl`, they are put in different RequireJS contexts, otherwise the `baseUrl` of the second app would override the `baseUrl` of the first one, causing the incorrect loading of its modules:

```
// first-app/src/first-app.js
require.config({
    context: 'first-app',
    baseUrl: 'first-app/src',
})(['fist-app/app']);

// first-app/src/second-app.js
require.config({
    context: 'second-app',
    baseUrl: 'second-app/src',
})(['second-app/app']);
```

But putting them in context then causes the look up for the common modules to fail, as the modules are looked in the `baseUrl` of the context. Actually this happens only for the second app (second in order of loading), while the first app to be included in the page can load the common modules fine

#### Question

So how should I make the apps to correctly share the common modules? Am I approaching this wrong? Should I use something else than RequireJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context feature of RequireJS is really meant to be used to handle a case where you have to load two conflicting applications on the same page *and* the conflict cannot be resolved otherwise. The *way* you've written your code so far may have led you to want to have two `baseUrl` values, but there is nothing in your question that indicates that you *must* have two `baseUrl` values. There are ways to avoid it:

1. Modules that are part of a logical set of modules should load each other with relative paths. For instance, the module you give as example could be:

   ```
   // first-app/src/first-app/controllers/app-controller.js
   define([
       '../modules/controllers',
       '../services/app-service',
       'common/services/common-service'
   ], function (controllers) {
   ```
2. `paths` can be set to make it *look* like a module is directly under `baseUrl` even if it is not. You could have:

   ```
   paths: {
       'first-app': 'first-app/src'
       'second-app': 'second-app/src'
   }
   ```

   and yes, loading `first-app/app` will work. RequireJS will transform the path to `first-app/src/app.js`.

Comment: Thanks, defining an "alias" for paths worked liked a charm!